# Compilation issues on linux

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, ubuntu

So I wrote the following code in linux(Ubuntu) using the emacs text editor it basically supposed to split the string on the delimeter passed in .  When I ran it it segfaulted I ran it though GDB and it gives me an error at strcpy(which I don't invoke) but is probably done implicitly in sprintf.  I didn't think I was doing anything wrong so I booted into windows and ran   it through visual studio and it works fine I am new to writing C in Linux and know the problem is in the While loop where i call sprintf() (which is odd because the call outside of the loop  writes without causing an error) to write the token to the array. If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  Here is the code

```
/*    split()
 Description:
 - takes a string and splits it into substrings "on" the 
 <delimeter>*/
void split(char *string, char *delimiter)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char *token;

    //large temporary buffer to over compensate for the fact that we have
    //no idea how many arguments will be passed with a command
    char *bigBuffer[25];

    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        bigBuffer[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    }

    //get the first token and add it to <tokens> 
    token = strtok(string, delimiter);
    sprintf(bigBuffer[0], "%s", token);

    //while we have not encountered the end of the string keep
    //splitting on the delimeter and adding to <bigBuffer>
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        sprintf(bigBuffer[++count], "%s", token);
    }

    //for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    //printf("i = %d : %s\n", i, bigBuffer[i]);
    for(i = 0; i< 25; i++)
    {
        free(bigBuffer[i]);
    }

} //end split()
```

Comment: Your issue isn't with compilation on linux -- it is with a program you are writing crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't checking for `NULL` from the return of `strtok` on the last iteration of the loop ... so `strtok` can return `NULL`, yet you still pass the `NULL` value in the `token` pointer to `sprintf`.

Change your while-loop to the following:

```
while(token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)) sprintf(bigBuffer[++count], "%s", token);
```

That way you can never pass a `NULL` pointer to `strtok` because the while-loop `NULL`-pointer check will enforce that `token` always has a valid value when `sprintf` is called with it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed my problem.  But do you know why it works in windows but not in Linux or is that just one of those situations where C behaves differently on different systems

Comment: It actually doesn't "work" on Windows... you just got lucky that it didn't crash ... that's why they call dereferencing a `NULL` pointer **undefined behavior** ... you might crash, or something more nefarious might occur that will leave you with a lot of head-scratching when some other mysterious value is corrupted in memory and you have no idea why :-)

Comment: You could just change the while loop to this: `while ((token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)))` and it would work fine.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : That's a very good suggestion ... I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask gdb for a full traceback of where your program crashed. The fact that you don't know precisely where it crashed means you didn't ask it for a full traceback, which is important.